# firebase.database() is not a function on local node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, local

I'm running a simple node app in my local machine and I need to connect to firebase realtime database.

I installed firebase via npm:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

Then I initialize the app:

```js
var firebase = require("firebase");

var config = {
    apiKey: "api-key",
    authDomain: "my-app-database.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://my-url.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "my-app-database.appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var myRef = firebase.database().ref("collection").on("value", (snap) => {
  // do something with the data
});
```

Then I get the error that database is not a function. I check `firebase.database` and is undefined, also so are `firebase.auth` and `firebase.storage`.

I followed all the steps in the docs, but I don't see anything that could be causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Goodness gracious... It was as simple as requiring the other packages in the file, like this:

```
// firebase
const firebase = require("firebase");
// get database, auth and storage
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/storage");
require("firebase/database");
```

Nowhere in the docs or reference says that. I thought about going back a version, perhaps 4.12.x, so I went to the npm page to see the previous versions and install one of those and try, when I found this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#include-only-the-features-you-need

Just scroll down where they mention using npm packages or Typescript and you'll find the answer.

Shout out to the Firebase team, this information can't be just in the npm page and not in the docs, getting started guides or the github repo. Not a lot of people goes to the npm page of a package for information and I went there to check previous versions, so I kind of stumbled upon it.